# How to preg_replace html tags

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have this `PHP` string

```
$str = '<span class="_21wk" style="background-image: url("/images/facebookEmojis/smileys/1f621.png");">';
```

And I want to replace the class and the url so I did this

```
$home = 'https://my-site.com';
$text = preg_replace('/<span class="_21wk" style="background-image: url("(.*?)");">/', '<span class="tinx" style="background-image: url("'.$home.'$1");">', $str);
```

But its not working. I want to have this at the replacement

```
<span class="tinx" style="background-image: url("https://my-site.com/images/facebookEmojis/smileys/1f621.png");">
```

Comment: I'm not sure the quotes you use to enclose the url reflects the reality, since the style attribute **and** the url are enclosed with double quotes. Could you post your real code? As an aside, regex are not designed to parse html, use DOMDocument instead, eventually with DOMXPath.

Comment: Parentheses are meta characters. It's often better to do step-by-step replacements (class= then css style=). If all fails, and this isn't performance-critical, or input less consistent (but still valid), go for QueryPath/phpQuery or another DOM traversal frontend.

Answer (score 0):

If You can't use regex, just try don't use it :P

```
$str = str_replace('/images', $home . "/images");
$str = str_replace('_21wk', $home . "tinx");
```

Answer (score 0):

If i read what you need correctly str_replace will work just fine without declaring additional variables

```
$str = '<span class="_21wk" style="background-image: url("/images/facebookEmojis/smileys/1f621.png");">';

$str = str_replace('_21wk','tinx',$str);
$str = str_replace('/images','https://my-site.com/images',$str);
```

Answer (score -1):

You simply forgot to escape the parenthesis characters in your regex, i.e. `url\(...\)` instead of `url(...)`:

```
$text = preg_replace('/<span class="_21wk" style="background-image: url\("(.*?)"\);">/', '<span class="tinx" style="background-image: url("'.$home.'$1");">', $str);
```